# Unable to start ubuntu through toolbox

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, container, podman

I just installed Fedora 35 Kinoite and am taking it for a test drive.
And, of course I am testing out the toolbox feature. Now I wanted to create & enter an Ubuntu container, it got created but somehow, toolbox doesn't allow me to enter it while it works as expected with podman natively. I'm getting the following:

```
$ toolbox create -i docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04
Image required to create toolbox container.
Download docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04 (500MB)? [y/N]: y
Creating container ubuntu-20.04: | Created container: ubuntu-20.04
Enter with: toolbox enter ubuntu-20.04
[ron@virtualFedora ron]$ toolbox enter ubuntu-20.04 
Error: command /bin/bash not found in container ubuntu-20.04
Using /bin/bash instead.
Error: command /bin/bash not found in container ubuntu-20.04
[ron@virtualFedora ron]$ toolbox list
IMAGE ID      IMAGE NAME                                    CREATED
ab8bc106d4a7  registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora-toolbox:35  2 weeks ago

CONTAINER ID  CONTAINER NAME  CREATED         STATUS      IMAGE NAME
6ceb30ae2785  dev             27 hours ago    configured  registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora-toolbox:35
475c506d23b0  ubuntu-20.04    32 seconds ago  running     docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04
$ podman run -it docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04
root@dc8572b5231a:/# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
root@dc8572b5231a:/#
```

When I enter, toolbox complains about a missing /bin/bash which obviously is not the case as can be seen when the container is entered with podman. I'm wondering wat I'm missing, can anyone shed some light onto this? :C

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do something similar on Silverblue & came across this question during my search.

It looks like images used have to be created specifically to work with toolbox and there's currently no officially-supported image.  That said, this Pull Request seems promising:
https://github.com/containers/toolbox/pull/483

Unofficial images are available at https://hub.docker.com/r/jmennius/ubuntu-toolbox